# Setting up Remote Desktop Web Client on Windows Server 2016 (without a domain)

Tags: windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services

The ultimate goal is to be able to visit https://example.com/RDWeb/webclient/index.html and be able to do a full Remote Desktop session in the browser.

My environment consists of a single Windows Server 2016 machine that I have administrative access to. I do not have the ability to deploy more machines into our environment. It's not on a domain (workgroup mode), and has an existing RDP setup that works just fine for multiple (local) users using the downloaded and installed Microsoft Remote Desktop Client for Windows and macOS.

From here, I've attempted to follow numerous sets of instructions that I've found while Googling, and I've been able to get to this state:
[image: Able to log in with local user credentials, same as Desktop RDP client, but there are no options to launch.]

So, it's deployed and appears to have at least the login bit correct. However, it offers no options to actually launch anything. It's my understanding that Remote Apps as well as Remote Desktops should be available here. I have not attempted, nor do I have a use case for Remote Apps, only the ability to allow the user to remote desktop via web into the same machine in question and have a full Remote Desktop experience, just via web.

I've read through a number of resources trying to find what I'm missing.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-web-client-admin
- http://woshub.com/rds-html5-web-client/
- [set up remote desktop server on windows server 2012](https://serverfault.com/questions/502727/set-up-remote-desktop-server-on-windows-server-2012)
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/90b55e69-937e-4c94-a6cf-e8045028bb7e/nothing-showing-in-remoteapp-programs-on-web-access?forum=winserverTS
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731450(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5974.remoteapp-troubleshooting-programs-listed-on-rd-web-access-site.aspx
- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/376039-hellppp-all-my-published-app-icons-on-rdweb-site-are-missing

Any help or pointers that could save my sanity are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for a few of my users was to have them log into the RDWEB site. Once they say the icons there. then They would go back to the Web Client and then they were able to see the icons.